# Text not displaying properly in container (swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIlabel and I want to adjust the texts alignment for when there isn't enough text to fill the views frame. I have included two screenshots to better illustrate what exactly I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: First Image]

Notice how the text is in the middle.

[image: Second Image]

Notice how the text now starts at the top left corner

Any suggestions?

Comment: so is your question that you want to center the lines of text vertically within the UILabel based on how many lines of text there really is?

Comment: I just want the text to always begin from the top left corner of the container

Answer (score 0):

Then set UILabel constraints, to be anchored to the top and to the left of container..

```
 yourLabel.topAnchor.constraintsEqual(yourContainer.topanchor).isActive = true

           yourLabel.leftAnchor.constraintsEqual(yourContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

Dont forget to set

```
     yourLabel.translatesAutoresizingMasks = false
```

Before you set constraints

Answer (score 0):

You could use `urLabel.sizeToFit()`.

1.set the width you want.

2.let height adjust according to content.